# with cmake how to link some libs statically and others dynamically?

Tags: c++, dynamic, static, linker, cmake

How to tell CMake to link statically some libs and dynamically others ?

I want to compile a C++ exe statically linked to all its dependencies libs except glic

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CMake approach to libraries is to first find them with `find_library` then use the result in `target_link_libraries`.

The choice of using a static or dynamic library is made during the `find_library` call:

- if you don't mind which version is used, just call `find_library(MYLIB mylib)`
- if you want a static library, use `find_library(MYLIB libmylib.a)` (that's for linux, you will search for a .lib on windows, etc.)
- if you want a dynamic library, use `find_library(MYLIB libmylib.so)`

Then test if you library is found with `if (MYLIB)` and link it to your target with: `target_link_libraries(mytarget ${MYLIB})`